# Terraform: Can't create vm behind lb with azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have a weird behavior when I try to create an azure lb with vm inside the backend pool in the same time.

I have on module to manage vm and one module to manage lb.
If I create lb first, all work fine but if I create both together, it doesn't work.

Here is my configuration (terraform 0.12.9, azure 1.33.1):

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "vm-if-lb-public-association" {
  count                   = var.azure_lb_public_backend_id != "" ? var.countvm : 0
  network_interface_id    = element(azurerm_network_interface.vm-if.*.id, count.index)
  ip_configuration_name   = "${var.workspace_config.prefix}-${var.profile}-${count.index + 1}"
  backend_address_pool_id = var.azure_lb_public_backend_id
}
```

var.azure_lb_public_backend_id come from my lb module

```
output "lb_id" {
  value = var.enable ? azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.lb-backend[0].id : ""
}

resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool" "lb-backend" {
  name                = "pool-1"
  count               = var.enable ? 1 : 0
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.lb-rg[0].name
  loadbalancer_id     = azurerm_lb.lb[0].id
}
```

When I run a plan I get the following:

```
Error: Invalid count argument

  on modules/vm/network.tf line 46, in resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "vm-if-lb-public-association":
  46:   count                   = var.azure_lb_public_backend_id != "" ? var.countvm : 0

The "count" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined
until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances will be created.
To work around this, use the -target argument to first apply only the
resources that the count depends on.
It's like the plan command doesn't understand vm creation depends on azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool
```

I voluntarily don't post all the code to avoid too big post, but doesn't hesitate to ask more if needed.

Do you have an idea why I get this behavior ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message describes, the `count` value must not depend on any values that Terraform won't know until after the apply is complete. In this case, it looks like `var.azure_lb_public_backend_id` is an ID of an object that won't be allocated until that object is created, and so Terraform doesn't know yet what value that will have and so it can't say for certain whether it will equal `""`.

To make this work, you'll instead need to make the decision based on something Terraform *does* know at plan time. One way to do that is to wrap your load balancer id value in an object so that the decision can be made based on whether the object is set at all:

```
variable "load_balancer" {
  type = object({
    backend_address_pool_id = string
  })
  default = null
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "vm-if-lb-public-association" {
  count                   = var.load_balancer != null ? var.countvm : 0
  network_interface_id    = element(azurerm_network_interface.vm-if.*.id, count.index)
  ip_configuration_name   = "${var.workspace_config.prefix}-${var.profile}-${count.index + 1}"
  backend_address_pool_id = var.load_balancer.backend_address_pool_id
}
```

Now the decision is based on whether the `var.load_balancer` object is null, rather than on the value of the `backend_address_pool_id` attribute inside it. Your calling module can then set that based on the same test it was using to decide how to set `var.enable` on the other module:

```
  load_balancer = var.load_balancer_enabled ? {
    backend_address_pool_id = module.load_balancer.lb_id
  } : null
```

Assuming that `var.load_balancer_enabled` is something known at plan time, this should now work, because Terraform can decide whether `load_balancer` is null and thus determine a value for `count` in all cases.

---

In the above I tried to stick as closely as possible to how you had things arranged in order to make it easier to see what changes I was proposing, but there are some different ways to arrange the above principle that might make the modules easier to use for callers. Below are some examples that are more drastically different than what you shared, showing how we might hide the details of this handoff in the module interfaces themselves in order to achieve cleaner [module composition](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/composition.html).

In your root module:

```
variable "load_balancer_enabled" {
  type    = bool
  default = false
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example"
  location = "West US"
}

module "load_balancer" {
  source = "./modules/load-balancer"

  resource_group = azurerm_resource_group.example
  enabled        = var.load_balancer_enabled
}

module "virtual_machines" {
  source = "./modules/virtual_machines"

  resource_group = azurerm_resource_group.example
  vm_count       = 4
  load_balancer  = module.load_balancer
}
```

In the `load-balancer` module:

```
variable "resource_group" {
  type = object({
    name     = string
    location = string
  })
}

variable "enabled" {
  type    = bool
  default = true
}

resource "azurerm_lb" "example" {
  count = var.enabled ? 1 : 0

  name = "example"

  resource_group_name = var.resource_group.name
  location            = var.resource_group.location

  # (and probably a frontend IP allocation)
}

resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool" "example" {
  count = length(azurerm_lb.example)

  name                = "example"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group.name
  loadbalancer_id     = azurerm_lb.lb[count.index].id
}

output "backend_address_pool" {
  # Set only if the load balancer is enabled. Null otherwise.
  value = var.enabled ? azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.example[0] : null
}
```

In the `virtual-machine` module:

```
variable "resource_group" {
  type = object({
    name     = string
    location = string
  })
}

variable "vm_count" {
  type = number
}

variable "load_balancer" {
  type = object({
    # We only need to specify the subset of the module outputs
    # that we need here.
    backend_address_pool = object({
      id = string
    })
  })
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "example" {
  count = var.vm_count

  # (and whatever other settings you need here)
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "vm-if-lb-public-association" {
  count = var.load_balancer.backend_address_pool != null ? var.vm_count : 0

  network_interface_id    = azurerm_network_interface.example[count.index].id
  backend_address_pool_id = var.load_balancer.backend_address_pool.id
}
```

In this variant, the `load-balancer` module produces an object representing the backend address pool and deals with setting it to `null` when the module is disabled. We can then just pass the whole module result into the `virtual-machine` module and let it make the decision based on the `null`-ness of that object, and the calling module is just simple wiring of the modules together without any special logic.

Again, the important detail is that the decision is ultimately made based only on the `var.load_balancer_enabled` variable (indirectly), and not on any values that Terraform will learn during apply.